# Date validation in angular

Tags: angular

I have a modal form that has an input field called birthday. I want to validate the field if it is empty and the birthdate is greater than today's day

***THIS IS THE HTML PART***

```
<div class="form-group row">
          <label class="col-sm-5 col-form-label font-weight-bold text-right">{{resources.candidateModalBirthday}}:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input #birthdayDate="ngModel"
                   [(ngModel)]="candidate.birthdayDate"
                   class="form-control" name="birthdayDate"
                   type="date">

               <div *ngIf="birthdayDate.errors?.emptyField" class="text-danger">
                {{resources.emptyError}}
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="birthdayDate.errors?.dateInvalid" class="text-danger">
                {{resources.invalidBirthDateError}}
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```

***THE TYPESCRIPT PART***

```
// birthDate date validation
      if (this.candidate.birthdayDate === null || this.candidate.birthdayDate === undefined) {
        form.controls.birthdayDate.setErrors({emptyField: true});
        this.validForm = false;
      } else if (this.candidate.birthdayDate.toString() === '') {
        form.controls.birthdayDate.setErrors({emptyField: true});
        this.validForm = false;
      } else if (this.candidate.birthdayDate > this.today) { // check if birthDate is greater than currentDate
          form.controls.birthdayDate.setErrors({dateInvalid: true});
          this.validForm = false;
      }
```